# dbase replacement

Tags: replace, dbase

I have a few applications written in dbase 3 plus which I use for accounting purposes. Even though they get the job done I would like to migrate them to a modern language. What are my alternatives?

Comment: Do you have any other development language strengths?  Are you looking for browser / internet based solutions, or all in-house only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having any other skill sets that you can state, you can jump to almost anything.  Me personally, coming from Visual Foxpro, and having exposure to object-oriented design, coding since 1993, it was a relatively easy shift into C#.  As far as pushing into a different database from dBase III Plus, there is a ton of great support here in the MySql world along with all other languages too.  Good luck.

Comment: You could have a look at Vulcan.NET, which is a descendant of Clipper, another xBase language (via CA Visual Objects) - but I don't know how much help that would be, as opposed to using something like C#. Might be worth a glance though. We use Visual Objects here, but with SQL Server (and Oracle) rather than DBF databases.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, commissioned me to migrate all my .dbf files to MySQL, a library, currently runs on Linux, developed in php, if you want to use it, here's the link and an example of how easy it generates .sql files
https://github.com/julio899/migracionesDBF
I hope you can be useful.

```
// folder containing DBF files
$directorio_de_archivos = "./DBFWEB/";
$archivos_dbf=array('01INV.DBF','01_INV.DBF','02_CHE.DBF','02_CPC.DBF');
    foreach ($archivos_dbf as $key => $archivo) {
        $ruta=$directorio_de_archivos.$archivo;
            $obj=new DBF($ruta);
            $obj->tabla_y_datos();
    }
```